# How to set default select in TwinColSelect Vaadin

Tags: select, default, vaadin

I want preselect items in the containerAllClienteByAsociado, I try to preselect the same items in the containerAllCliente but also not found, sorry for bad english.

```
TwinColSelect colListClientes = new TwinColSelect();

private generateColListClientes(Asociado asociadoInstance){
    clienteController = new ClienteController();

    //Obtenemos el container con los datos
    BeanItemContainer<Cliente> containerAllCliente = new BeanItemContainer<Cliente>(Cliente.class);
    containerAllCliente.addAll(clienteController.getCollectionCliente());

    BeanItemContainer<Cliente> containerAllClienteByAsociado = new BeanItemContainer<Cliente>(Cliente.class);
    containerAllClienteByAsociado.addAll(asociadoInstance.getClientes());



    colListClientes.setMultiSelect(true);
    colListClientes.setImmediate(true);
    colListClientes.setContainerDataSource(containerAllCliente);
    colListClientes.setLeftColumnCaption("Listado de Clientes");
    colListClientes.setRightColumnCaption("Clientes del Asociado");
    colListClientes.setMultiSelect(true);


    for (clienteTotales in containerAllCliente){

        colListClientes.setValue(clienteTotales);

    }

    return colListClientes;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution, work fine in my code.

```
private generateColListClientes(Asociado asociadoInstance){

        clienteController = new ClienteController();


        //DEFINITION OF CONTAINERS
        HashSet<Cliente> containerAllCliente = new HashSet<Cliente>();
        containerAllCliente.addAll(clienteController.getCollectionCliente());

        HashSet<Cliente>  containerAllClienteByAsociado = new HashSet<Cliente>()
        containerAllClienteByAsociado.addAll(asociadoInstance.getClientes())

        //DEFINITION OF TWINCOLUMN
        colListClientes.setLeftColumnCaption("Listado de Clientes");
        colListClientes.setRightColumnCaption("Clientes del Asociado");
        colListClientes.setMultiSelect(true);
        colListClientes.setWidth("350px");
        colListClientes.setImmediate(true);

        HashSet<Cliente> preselected = new HashSet<Cliente>();

        //TOUR TOTAL CLIENTS
        for (Cliente cliente : containerAllCliente){
            colListClientes.addItem(cliente);
            //WE COMPARE TOTAL CLIENTS TO ASOCIADO.CLIENTES
            for(Cliente clienteAsociado : containerAllClienteByAsociado) {
                //COMPARE IDS AND PRESELECT IF IS THE SAME
              if(cliente.id==clienteAsociado.id){
                  preselected.add(cliente);
              }

            }
        }

        colListClientes.setValue(preselected);



        return colListClientes;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
`BeanItemContainer<Cliente> containerAllCliente = new BeanItemContainer<Cliente>(Cliente.class);`
```

Use this:

```
`BeanContainer<String,Cliente> containerAllCliente = new BeanContainer<String,Cliente>(Cliente.class);`
```

Also, while populating your twin-select, set its "id" property to be some identifying member variable/property of the Cliente.class

After populating, you can use:

`twin-select.setValue(<value of identifying member data of the particular Cliente instance>);`

This link might be of help:
https://dev.vaadin.com/svn/doc/book-examples/trunk/src/com/vaadin/book/examples/datamodel/BeanContainerExample.java

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using setValue(...) for each item, just use it once and pass the whole collection as argument.

When using setValue(...) with single items, it deselects the previously selected values.

Comment: I try with this  colListClientes.setValue(containerAllCliente), but dont work